# pandas df.plot() not working - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Trying to use df.plot() and I keep getting the below error - I think it might be caused to pandas version?

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

Plotting time series data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eksHJ.png)